# C# Reading line by line from file to listbox

Tags: c#, readline, line-by-line

I have a problem with reading text from file line by line.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("ais.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

This code only read last line from file and display in listbox. How can I read line-by-line?

For example: read a line, wait 1 second, read another line, wait 1 second...ect.?

Comment: Have you tried File.ReadAllLines () function?

Comment: I understand reading each line, but are these 1 second waits important? Why not just read in all the lines?

Comment: Incidentally, other than not declaring `line`, your code works fine.

Comment: @JonB is correct...what exactly is the problem?

Comment: " wait 1 second,"   Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: are you sure your file doesn't just contain 1 line?

Comment: He claims that only the last line appears in the listbox. I don't see how that could be the case based on the code provided.

Comment: thomas Yes i tried use ReadAllLine and it doesnt work. 
Steve Wellens I need to do that , because thanks that i can go to next step with my program. I make a program (AIS decode) which read coordinates from AIS simulator which are stored in txt and after that i can decode this. Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read lines one at a time with a one second delay, you can add a timer to your form to do this (set it to 1000):

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("ais.txt");
String line;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        file.Close();
    }
}
```

You could also read the lines all at once and simply display them one at a time, but I was trying to keep this as close to your code as possible.

Comment: It's quite important to close the reader when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

`await` makes this very easy.  We can just loop through all of the lines and `await Task.Delay` to asynchronously wait for a period of time before continuing, while still not blocking the UI thread.

```
public async Task DisplayLinesSlowly()
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("ais.txt"))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(line);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx)? You can do something like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach(string line in lines)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines and save to array string

```
  string[] file_lines = File.ReadAllLines("ais.txt");
```

and then read line by line by button click or use timer to wait 1 second